# Is this function producing any memory leak?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments

```
+ (NSArray *) fetchAllContactsInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)a_context
{
    NSFetchRequest *_request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [_request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:a_context]];

    NSSortDescriptor *_sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *_sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:_sortDescriptor, nil];
    [_request setSortDescriptors:_sortDescriptors];

    NSError *_fetchError=nil;
    NSArray *_results = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[a_context executeFetchRequest:_request error:&_fetchError]];
    [_sortDescriptor release];
    [_sortDescriptors release];
    [_request release];

    if (_fetchError){
        NSLog(@"Contact - Error fetching contacts %@", [_fetchError localizedDescription]);
    }
    [_fetchError release];
    return [_results autorelease];
}
```

I wanna ask, Is this function leaking memory? Actually Instruments is saying that this function is leaking hell lot of memory.

Can you please help me resolving the memory issue?

Comment: Note: do not test `_error` to determine if there is an error, test `_results`, there is no guarantee about the value if there is no error.. Also, these days leading underscores "_" are generally only used for iVars, this helps others to read your code. And of course with ARC all of this is a noun-issue.

Comment: I don't think you need to release `_fetchError`.  Otherwise, it's possible that whatever calls this is causing the returned value to leak.  Try running Product->Analyze to see if there are warnings...or switch to ARC.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to see where retains, releases and autoreleases occur for an object use instruments:

Run in instruments, in Allocations set "Record reference counts" on on (you have to stop recording to set the option). Cause the problem code to run, stop recording, search for there ivar of interest, drill down and you will be able to see where all retains, releases and autoreleases occurred.

[image]

Here is a simplifies version using ARC for iOS 4.3 and up:

```
+ (NSArray *) fetchAllContactsInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)aContext {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Contact"];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES];
    [request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

    NSError *fetchError;
    NSArray *results = [aContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError];

    if (results == nil){
        NSLog(@"Contact - Error fetching contacts %@", [fetchError localizedDescription]);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to change my project setting to use ARC? or refactoring this file will work? currently my project is NON-ARC Project.

Comment: Wether you use ARC or not is a personal preference, I choose to use ARC in my projects. YOu might look for another SO answer to how to convert to ARC.

Answer (score 0):

Why `[_fetchError release];` is there?

And Why don't you use ARC?

Try to refactor this code into ARC.

Comment: Do I need to change my project setting to use ARC? or refactoring this file will work? currently my project is NON-ARC Project.

Comment: Refactor it, it will be converted to ARC automatically. And in arc release, retain, copy, autorelease and implemented by compiler itself. so no chances of leaks and zombies.

Comment: Do I need to change my project setting to use ARC?

Comment: It will lessen your trouble but you should be aware of cocoa-memory management.